# Django Url regex NoReverseMatch error

Tags: python, html, regex, django

Have this html, that i want to pass 2 arguments to a function when that url is pressed:

htmlpage

```
{% for n in notifications %}
                    <li style="..."><b>{{ n.title }}</b> - {{ n.description }}
                    <a href="{% url 'update-notify-status' n.id n.title %}" >Don't show again</a>
{% endfor %}
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^notification_htmlv2/update_status/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{4})$', 'Notifications.views.updateStatus',
                       name="update-notify-status"),
```

views.py

```
def updateStatus(request,noteId,noteTile):
q=History.objects.filter(notification_id=noteId,title=noteTile).order_by('-id')[0]
```

When i start the program it gives an error of "NoReverseMatch".
Im following this example:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/

reverse resolution of url's chapter

Comment: n.title is probably a string which would not be matched by ([0-9]{4}), you would need something like this: [\w-]+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet neither `n.id` nor `n.title` matches `([0-9]{4})`.

You should update your url pattern to handle any possible `id` and `title` values.

Something like:

```
r'^notification_htmlv2/update_status/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$'
```

Comment: Ive added what you suggested, but continues to give that error.
`Reverse for 'update-notify-status' with arguments '(4L, u'EUW')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['notification_htmlv2/update_status/([0-9]{4})/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$']`

Comment: @Zecarlos You have not replaced the pattern for `id` (you still have `([0-9]{4})`, I suggested `([0-9]+)`), the `{4}` means it only matches a length of 4, the length of your `id` is 1. The `+` means match one character or more.